# How many clients are connected to channel

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, task-queue, channel-api

I have a process that is running from a task queue that periodically sends messages through a channel to the client.

Is it possible to check if the client is still connected to see if the task queue should be sending messages or not?

I can see this happening if the client page with channel javascript has not yet loaded or they have closed the browser window. In either case I would rather the task queue process not send messages to the client.

Answer (score 1):

When the client opens or closes the connection it posts to /_ah/channel/[dis]connected.  Assuming you maintain a list of client_ids on the server, the client_id sent in the post will let you track open/closed client_ids.

This has been consistent for me but there are a few post on the google group where this is not behaving as expected.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview#Tracking_Client_Connections_and_Disconnections

Comment: Humpf. I don't like this. google.appengine.api.channel should have a method for this.